# Firebase AuthUI - Uknown Error Code only in production

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase AuthUI 3.3.0 for authentification via mobile number, the problem is that in debug mode it's working, but in production not (release mode), I get an error,

> Unknown Error Code

Any ideas to solve this problem? What am I missing? the SHA1 fingerprint is added in firebase and google-services.json seems ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I succeeded to solve this problem. I used debug fingerprint, not release one. Also, you need to add in firebase all generated keystores (SHA1), you can do this by running **App - Taks - Android - Signin Report** in Android Studio

More information about how you can generate one and use  [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth)